# Critical case of Sobolev Embedding

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

I got stuck in the following lemma:

**Lemma:** Let $B$ be the unit ball in the 4 dimensional Euclidean space. Suppose that $u\in W^{2,2}(B)$, then $e^{u}\in L^{q}$ for any $q>1$.

As we know this is exactly the critical case of Sobolev's imbedding where we fail to get $L^{\infty}$ bounds. Any suggestion and help would be appreciated.

**My idea of this that fails**:

Note $\int_{B} e^{pu}\leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{p^{k}}{k!}\int_{B} |u|^{k}$. By Sobolev imbedding we know that $W^{2,2}(B)\hookrightarrow L^{k}$ for any $k\geq 1$. So we know that

$$\parallel u\parallel_{L^{k}(B)}\leq C_{k} \parallel u \parallel_{W^{2,2}} $$

We can then get :

$\int_{B} e^{pu}\leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{p^{k}}{k!} (C_{k})^{k} \parallel u \parallel_{W^{2,2}}^{k}$.

So that it suffices to control $C_{k}$. But based on my calculation, $C_{k} \sim k$, from which it seems this argument would fail.

Comment: I believe you are looking for the Moser-Trudinger inequality... Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birnbaum%E2%80%93Orlicz_space (the Wikipedia entry on the Moser-Trudinger inequality is not that illuminating by itself)

Comment: The edit seems to have incorporated the answer to the OP's question. May I suggest dismembering it and making it into a proper answer?

Comment: @PedroLauridsenRibeiro Hi, please feel free to edit the original post.

Comment: Done, I essentially reverted your question to its original form (apart only from a couple of corrections). I also picked a version of the Trudinger inequality which applies more directly to your hypotheses (with a proper reference to the excellent book of Gilbarg and Trudinger) and completed the argument you sketched based on my comment above. Finally, I made a few remarks about why you really need $u\in W^{2,2}_0(B)$ for the estimate to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed in my comment above, what you seem to be looking for is [Trudinger's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birnbaum%E2%80%93Orlicz_space#Relations_to_Sobolev_spaces) (see e.g. formula (7.40), pp. 162 of the book *Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order* by D. Gilbarg and N.S. Trudinger (Springer-Verlag, 1998)), with the proviso that in fact you need $u\in W^{2,2}_0(B)=$ closure of $\mathscr{C}^\infty_c(B)$ in $W^{2,2}(B)$. Since $B$ has Lipschitz boundary, Trudinger's inequality states that for all $u\in W^{2,2}_0(B)$ there are constants $C_1,C_2>0$ such that $$\tag{1}\label{e1}\int_B\exp\left(\left(\frac{|u(x)|}{C_1\|D^2 u\|_2}\right)^2\right)\mathrm{d}x\leq C_2|B|\ ,$$ where $|B|$ stands for the Lebesgue measure of $B$. Notice that if $u$ is constant on $B$ then $\|D^2 u\|_2=0$ and in this case the left hand side of the above inequality equals $+\infty$, hence the need for taking $u\in W^{2,2}_0(B)$.

It is not difficult to infer from inequality \eqref{e1} that $e^u\in L^q(B)$ for all $q>0$. To that end, set $a=C_1\|D^2 u\|_2$ ($>0$!) and notice that whenever $|u(x)|\geq a^2 q$ we have that $e^{q|u(x)|}\leq e^{(\frac{|u(x)|}{a})^2}$ and whenever $|u(x)|\leq a^2 q$ we have that $e^{q|u(x)|}\leq e^{a^2q^2}$. Therefore $$\int_B |e^{u(x)}|^q\mathrm{d}x\leq\int_B e^{q|u(x)|}\mathrm{d}x\leq e^{a^2q^2}|B|+\int_B e^{(\frac{|u(x)|}{a})^2}\mathrm{d}x\leq (e^{a^2q^2}+C_2)|B|<\infty\ ,$$ as desired.

Trudinger's inequality can indeed be seen as a sharpening of Sobolev's embedding theorem. Interestingly, Trudinger's original argument ([*On Imbeddings into Orlicz Spaces and Some Applications*](http://www.iumj.indiana.edu/oai/1968/17/17028/17028.xml), J. Math. Mech. **17** (1967) 473-483) is not far off what you were trying to do - it consisted in controlling each individual term in the power series for the exponential but that involved estimating the action of certain Riesz potentials.